# How to query count on the pivot table in Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two data tables in database. One is user table, other one is property table. User can save as many properties as they want. Also, one property can be save by multiple users. So there is a pivot table which has the property_id and user_id in it for a record.  Now I want to query the popular properties. All properties that is saved by more than 100 users are popular properties. How would I do that? Something like I am doing

```
public function popularProperties(Request $request)
    {
       $id = $request->id;
        return Property::where('saved'->count(),'>',100)->with([
            'paymentPlan' => function ($query){
                $query->select('property_id','all_in_one_go','down_payment','minimum_installment_per_month');
            },
            'city',
            'propertyType' => function ($query){
                $query->select('id','name');
            },
            'user' => function ($query){
            $query->select('id','name','email');
        },
        'images' => function($query){
            $query->select('imageable_id','url');
        }
        ])->withCount('likes')->get();
    }
```

Comment: did you try ->withCount('saved')->having('saved_count', '>', 100);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code selects all property's with > 100 count. Inside the whereIn is a subquery that selects all property IDs that exist > 100 times. Note that you have to fill in the correct Table and column names

```
$propertys = Property::whereIn('id', function ($q){
            $q->select('property_id')
            ->from('user_property')
            ->groupBy('property_id')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 100');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked. But I am trying to find a solution that is usable with eloquent model.
Thanks again

Comment: I updated my answer. It now selects the property's with eloquent resulting in a Collection of property's